# ERROR when using count in R which was working before

Tags: r, count, compiler-errors

i used `count` in order to count the same rows and get the frequency and it was working very well like 2 hours ago and now it's giving me an ERROR that i do not understand. I wanted that every time i have the same row, add the concentration of these rows. Here is my toy data and my function.

```
df=data.frame(ID=seq(1:6),A=rep(0,6),B=c(rep(0,5),1),C=c(rep(1,5),0),D=rep(1,6),E=c(rep(0,3),rep(1,2),0),concentration=c(0.002,0.004,0.001,0.0075,0.00398,0.006))
 df
  ID A B C D E concentration
1  1 0 0 1 1 0       0.00200
2  2 0 0 1 1 0       0.00400
3  3 0 0 1 1 0       0.00100
4  4 0 0 1 1 1       0.00750
5  5 0 0 1 1 1       0.00398
6  6 0 1 0 1 0       0.00600

freq.concentration=function(df,Vars){
  df=data.frame(df)
  Vars=as.character(Vars)
  compte=count(df,Vars)
  frequence.C= (compte$freq)/nrow(df)
  output=cbind(compte,frequence.C)
  return(output)
}

freq.concentration(df,colnames(df[2:6]))

# and here is the error that i get when i run the function which was working perfectly a while ago!
#  Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
# * Column `Vars` is not found.
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

PS: I do not know if this is related or not but i got this problem when i opened a script Rmd and did copy paste all my function to this script and all of a sudden my function stopped working .
I really appreciate your help in advance. Thank you.

Here is the output that i had when it was working properly :

```
 output
  ID A B C D E  concentration.C.1 concentration.C.2
1  1 0 0 1 1 0          3                0.007
2  4 0 0 1 1 1          2                0.01148
3  6 0 1 0 1 0          1                0.00600
```

The first 3 rows are similar so we sum the concentration of the 3 and get 0.007, and then rows 4 and 5 are the same so we add their concentration and get 0.01148 and the last row is unique so the concentration remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!!`) in `count` to get the frequency count based on those columns and then get the 'frequence.C' as the proportion of 'n' with the `sum` of that count

```
library(dplyr)
freq.concentration <- function(df, Vars){
     df  %>%     
      count(!!! rlang::syms(Vars))  %>%
      mutate(frequence.C = n/sum(n))
      
    }
```

-testing

```
freq.concentration(df,colnames(df)[2:6])
#  A B C D E n frequence.C
#1 0 0 1 1 0 3   0.5000000
#2 0 0 1 1 1 2   0.3333333
#3 0 1 0 1 0 1   0.1666667
```

---

If we need the `sum` of 'concentration', we could use a `group_by` operation instead of `count`

```
freq.concentration <- function(df, Vars){
     df  %>% 
        group_by(across(all_of(Vars))) %>%
        summarise(n = n(), frequency.C = sum(concentration), .groups = 'drop')
   }
```

-testing

```
freq.concentration(df,colnames(df)[2:6])
# A tibble: 3 x 7
#      A     B     C     D     E     n frequency.C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>       <dbl>
#1     0     0     1     1     0     3      0.007 
#2     0     0     1     1     1     2      0.0115
#3     0     1     0     1     0     1      0.006
```

Comment: It is indeed not giving any error but still not giving me the desire output, i will add the output that i had in the post.

Comment: @Janet I added the frequency.C.  Earlier, I just wanted to show where the error was

Comment: take a look, i edited the post so you can see the expected output. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am extremly sorry! you are right @akrun It was my mistake i should get 0.5 cuz 3/6 gives 0.5.

Comment: @Janet I changed the calculation based on your new expecetd output assuming that it is the `sum` of concentration

Comment: Thank you @akrun actually you gave me another answer to another problem i was having. I apologize if i was not clear at first. I really appreciate your help. i am going to use both your answers! Thank you again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222758/discussion-between-janet-and-akrun).